# Select items from a list after the first occurrence of a character

Tags: c#, linq

Given a list like this:

```
["singing", "office", "1995>Work Photos", "Kevin", "and", "Emma", "Holiday Party>Karaoke"]
```

What's the most concise LINQ query to select the first element in the list that includes the character '>' and all elements after it. For the example above, I'd like this result:

```
["1995>Work Photos", "Kevin", "and", "Emma", "Holiday Party>Karaoke"]
```

I could obviously loop through and do it manually but it feels like there's an elegant one-liner out there. Here's the manual attempt:

```
var found = false;
var filtered = new List<string>();
foreach (var itm in list){
   if (itm.Contains(">")) found = true;
   if (found) filtered.Add(itm);
}
Console.WriteLine(filtered);
```

Comment: I've already done it using a loop. Just wondering if there's an elegant LINQ query that I'm missing.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are seeking [`SkipWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var ar = new string []{ "singing", "office", "1995>Work Photos", "Kevin", "and", "Emma", "Holiday Party>Karaoke"};
var r= ar.SkipWhile(s => !s.Contains(">"));
```